# Get data from selected dropdown option in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, dropdown

What I have from JSON resend is :

```
 "meal" : {
"id" : 354,
"unit" : "cup",
"disable" : "0",
"created_at" : "2017-04-17 13:09:12",
"small" : "0",
"type" : "7",
"price" : "0",
"image" : "da6ddbab1f7b8b37a536c353fac16e3958f4be78022f6.png",
"family_id" : "125",
"updated_at" : "2017-04-17 13:32:41",
"deleted_at" : null,
"medium" : "10",
"large" : "30",
"name" : "Grapefruit"
```

}

For example this juice has tow sizes 'medium' and 'large'. In the dropdown I wish to display only the sizes that have prices, ONLY sizes, and when user chooses the size I wish to print it's price and the selected size. So I found this library and I've been trying to figure out a way to successfully achieve what I want but no luck because it will show me only the selected item without the size of the item ( or selected price without the size of the price)

```
 @IBAction func placeDropdown(_ sender: Any) {

    Size.show()

}

func sizeShow() {
    Size.anchorView = Size
    Size.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: sizebtn.bounds.height)
    // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
    let prices = [sSize , mSize , lSize]
    print(prices)
    var newPrices = [String]()
    print(newPrices)
    for i in prices {

        if i != "0"{

            newPrices.append(i)
        }
    }

    Size.dataSource = newPrices
    // Action triggered on selection
    Size.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
        self.sizebtn.setTitle(item, for: .normal)

        print(self.Size.selectedItem)
    }

}
```

Is there any way or library that can help me ?

Comment: your json seems strange if you want to use different prices

Comment: is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Vyacheslav is right, your json is weird for this purpose, especially if different meals can have different types of sizes. Try structuring your json like this:

```
“meal”:{
       // ...
        “sizes”: [{“type”:”medium”, “price”: 10}, {“type”:”large”, “price”: 30}]
    }
```

That way you can get the array of different sizes like this:

```
availableSizes = (mealJSON[“sizes”] as? [[String: AnyObject]]) ?? []
```

Although your Size variable, which I assume is your dropdown UI will have to adapt its inputs. If you only want prices that are greater than 0, add this:

```
availableSizes = availableSizes.filter { ($0[“price”] as? Int) ?? 0 > 0 }
```

When the Size has been selected, hopefully your function will get the index of the sizes array that the user selected as a parameter so you can access the selected size with:

```
availableSizes[selectedIndex][“type”]
```

Comment: Thank you for your deliberate answer. I still have to follow the structure given to me and no way to change it. Is there a way to structure JSON in swift to make it easy to display ?

Comment: There are some libraries that can help swift’s json compatibility (SwiftyJSON is a well-known one), and conversion between structures and JSON is coming natively to the language in Swift 4. Displaying JSON is quite different though. You could do anything from showing the raw text on a label to creating a custom control or view to show your values. You could get an array of your sizes with this code: `availableSizes = mealJSON.keys.filter { sizes.contains($0) }` where `sizes` is an array of possible sizes such as `[“medium”, “large”]`.